# JSON and nested NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsdictionary

After parsing a JSON response, I get an NSDictionary containing other dictionaries which are the values for some keys not known in advance (308, 1):

```
{
"308":{
    "id":"308",
    .....

},
"1":{
    "id":"1",
    .....
     }
}
```

How do I use here valueForKey since I dont' know the keys? How to acces the nested dictionaries? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *myDict;
...

NSArray *keys = [myDict allKeys]; //NSArray of dictionary's keys

for (id key in keys) //'foreach' loop for all keys
{
   id aValue = [myDict objectForKey: key]; //getting object from the dictionary
   if([aValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
   {
       //Object is a nested dictionary
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to iterate over an `NSDictionary`. One of them:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myDictionary objectEnumerator];
id value;

while ((value = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    /* do something with value */
}
```

Look "Enumerating Dictionaries" section in [NSDictionary Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more alternatives.